# What is the technical term for "Mixed units of measurement"?

Tags: vocabulario-técnico

In English the term "Mixed units of measurement" stands for measures that require or use two or more basic units. For instance, adding 3 hours 22 minutes and 5 hours 10 minutes results in 8 hours 32 minutes, the mixed units of measurement are the hours and minutes used together to measure time.

I haven't been able to find this term in Spanish, "Unidades de medida mixta" doesn't seem to be the technical term, neither "Unidades de medición mixta", nor "Unidades de medida combinada", nor "Unidades de medición combinada", is there a technical term in Spanish for "Mixed units of measurement"? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use "unidades de medida mixtas". Notice that "mixtas" should be in the plural: what is mixed is the units (plural), not the measurement (singular).

There are several examples on the Internet, for example, this one ([Source](https://las-matematicas.com/1-11-sistemas-de-medida/)):

> Usar unidades de medida mixtas en el sistema de los EE. UU.
>
> A menudo utilizamos unidades de medida mixtas en situaciones cotidianas. Supongamos que Joe mide 5 pies y 10 pulgadas de alto, permanece en el trabajo durante 7 horas y 45 minutos y luego come un filete de 1 libra y 2 onzas para la cena: todas estas medidas tienen unidades mixtas.
>
> Realizar operaciones aritméticas en mediciones con unidades mixtas de medidas requiere cuidado. ¡Asegúrese de sumar o restar unidades similares!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please show more context about the use of "unidades de medida mixtas" in the book? Does it refer to the same term as "mixed units of measurement"? In that case, the step one proposed in the book means that one should convert all units in the mix to a single unit of measure, before converting it to another unit?

Comment: Sorry. I think the author of the book uses "mixtas" to mean "heterogéneas". I've changed the example.